# How do I get the data of a related object to my view? CakePhP

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to get a text to my view but this doesn't seem to work out.

In my WepagesController.php I have a function for my aboutus.ctp:

```
        public function aboutus() {

        // load the website base-layout
        $this -> layout = 'website';

        // load relevant models
        $this -> loadModel('Contentitem');


    //query for 2 contentitems
    $aboutusinfos = $this->Contentitem->find('first', array('conditions' => array('contentitem_slug' => 'lorum')));
    debug($aboutusinfos);
    $aboutuspersons = $this->Contentitem->find('first', array('conditions' => array('contentitem_slug' => 'Robotics')));
    debug($aboutuspersons);
   //set the 2 contentitems     
    $this->set('aboutusinfos', $this->Contentitem->find('first', array('conditions' => array('contentitem_slug' => 'lorum'))));
    $this->set('aboutuspersons', $this->Contentitem->find('first', array('conditions' => array('contentitem_slug' => 'Robotics'))));


    }
```

This gives me the correct contentitems output:

```
array(
    'Contentitem' => array(
        'contentitem_id' => '4',
        'contentitem_slug' => 'lorum',
        'contentitem_note' => ''
    ),
    'Contenttext' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'contenttext_id' => '4',
            'contenttext_text' => '<p><span style="color: #555555; font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12.8px; text-align: justify;">A butt load of text</span></p>',
            'contenttext_rel_contentitem' => '4',
            'contenttext_rel_language' => '2'
        )
    )
)

array(
    'Contentitem' => array(
        'contentitem_id' => '3',
        'contentitem_slug' => 'Robotics',
        'contentitem_note' => ''
    ),
    'Contenttext' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'contenttext_id' => '3',
            'contenttext_text' => '<p><span style="color: #555555; font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12.8px; text-align: justify;">A butt load of text</span></p>',
            'contenttext_rel_contentitem' => '3',
            'contenttext_rel_language' => '2'
        )
    )
)
```

My problem now is I cant request contenttext_text in my about.ctp like this:

```
<div class="column_2">
<?php
echo $aboutusinfos['Contenttext']['contenttext_text'];

?>
</div>
```

It does work whenever I want to acess anything from `$aboutusinfos['Contentitem']` just not from the related table.
Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $aboutusinfos['Contenttext'][0]['contenttext_text'];
```

Should do the trick

Comment: You sir, are a hero.